# How to best index/deconstruction json objects when joining across tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

So I'm having a bit of a dilemma. I have data in two tables where it looks a little like this:

Table 1:
Field A:

```
["ABC","123","doReMi"]
```

Table 2:
Field B:

```
["QWE","ASD","ZXC"]
```

The data is just a JSON array of strings with no key/value pairs to then deconstruct and place indexes on them.

I have to do a bit of a nasty join like this:

```
table1 
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON JSON_SEARCH(table1.fieldA,one,table2.fieldB) IS NOT NULL
```

Am a little bit stuck as to the best approach to tackle this as the performance of the search is relatively abysmal. Any hints/tips would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in JSON function which checks JSON arrays for overlapping (rather than objects). Parse one array to elements then check value-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to design the schema based on how the data will be used.

A JSON column is handy for holding a collection of miscellany info *that you don't need to inspect via SQL*.  If you need to frequently parse it, then it would be better to do the parsing *before* putting data into the table.

That is, put a named attribute into a column of its own.  And give that column a suitable datatype.  Or, in your case, turn an array into rows of a table.  Your `table1` would need another `table1A` with, in your example, 3 rows, one for each value, plus an id so that it could be `JOINed` to `table1` for whatever else there is.

`table1A` could easily have an `INDEX` on that column.